# How to create a common config file for database?

Tags: sql, database, generics, configuration-files

I need to create a file that will define the schema of the database containing ***tables*** , ***attributes*** , ***relations*** . It will **not** contain any **tuples** or **data values**.
The file needs to be a generic one, i.e, it must be adaptable to every database(sqlite, mysql, sql server, db2, oracle X, etc.).
How do i create such a file? What extension is best suitable? How to read from the file?
I am currently using Java to code. Please suggest something compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest standard SQL, avoiding to use any dialect expression from a specific DBMS. Only `CREATE TABLE` statements and similar.

Also XML could be ok, but SQL it's ready to be executed and... it's standard! Which is fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just stick with ANSI SQL paying attention to the [pitfalls described here](http://home.fnal.gov/~dbox/SQL_API_Portability.html).

If this is not you are looking for then look at the [**Apache Torque**](http://db.apache.org/torque/). It lets you define your DB schema and then it can generate and execute SQL out of it. We use Torque for similar kind of use case.